# Add show all pages button to JQuery pagination code?

Tags: jquery, button, pagination, addition

I am using the following pagination script and would like to know if someone can teach me how to add a show all button to the existing logic?

I think I understand I can edit the "last text" to read total pages(?)

If I am going in the wrong direction or if someone can explain a different logic please do so.

```
(function($) {
 'use strict';

  var Paginator = function() {
return {
  // Attributes
  obj: null,
  options: null,
  nav: null,

  // Methods
  build: function(obj, opts) {
    this.obj = obj;
    this.options = opts;

    if(!this.options.optional || this._totalRows() > this.options.limit)  
  {
      this._createNavigation();
      this._setPage();
    }

    if(this.options.onCreate) this.options.onCreate(obj);

    return this.obj;
  },

  _createNavigation: function() {
    this._createNavigationWrapper();
    this._createNavigationButtons();
    this._appendNavigation();
    this._addNavigationCallbacks();
  },
  _createNavigationWrapper: function() {
    this.nav = $('<div>', {
      class: this.options.navigationClass
    });
  },
  _createNavigationButtons: function() {
    // Add 'first' button
    if(this.options.first) {
      this._createNavigationButton(this.options.firstText, {
        'data-first': true
      });
    }

    // Add 'previous' button
    if(this.options.previous) {
      this._createNavigationButton(this.options.previousText, {
        'data-direction': -1,
        'data-previous': true
      });
    }

    // Add page buttons
    for(var i = 0; i < this._totalPages(); ++i) {
      this._createNavigationButton(this.options.pageToText(i), {
        'data-page': i
      });
    }

    // Add 'next' button
    if(this.options.next) {
      this._createNavigationButton(this.options.nextText, {
        'data-direction': 1,
        'data-next': true
      });
    }

    // Add 'last' button
    if(this.options.last) {
      this._createNavigationButton(this.options.lastText, {
        'data-last': true
      });
    }
  },
  _createNavigationButton: function(text, options) {
    this.nav.append($('<a>', $.extend(options, { href: '#', text: text    
  })));
  },
  _appendNavigation: function() {
    // Add the content to the navigation block
    if(this.options.navigationWrapper) 
  this.options.navigationWrapper.append(this.nav);
    // Add it after the table
    else this.obj.after(this.nav);
  },
  _addNavigationCallbacks: function() {
    var paginator = this;

    paginator.nav.find('a').click(function(e) {
      var direction = $(this).data('direction') * 1;

      // 'First' button
      if($(this).data('first') !== undefined) {
        paginator._setPage(0);
      }
      // Page button
      else if ($(this).data('page') !== undefined) {
        paginator._setPage($(this).data('page') * 1);
      }
      // 'Previous' or 'Next' button
      else if ($(this).data('previous') !== undefined || 
  $(this).data('next') !== undefined) {
        var page = paginator._currentPage() + direction;
        if(page >= 0 && page <= paginator._totalPages() - 1) {
          paginator._setPage(page);
        }
      }
      // 'Last' button
      else if ($(this).data('last') !== undefined) {
        paginator._setPage(paginator._totalPages());
      }

      // Handle callback
      if(paginator.options.onSelect) 
  paginator.options.onSelect(paginator.obj, paginator._currentPage());
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    });
  },

  _setPage: function(index) {
    if(index == undefined) index = this.options.initialPage;

    // Hide all elements, and then show the current page.
    this._rows().hide().slice(index * this.options.limit, (index + 1) * 
 this.options.limit).show();

    // Set the current button as active
    this.nav.find('a').removeAttr('data-selected').siblings('a[data-  
 page=' + index + ']')
            .attr('data-selected', true);
  },

  _currentPage: function() {
    return this.nav.find('a[data-selected=true]').data('page');
  },
  _totalRows: function() {
    // Count the total rows of the selector
    return this._rows().length;
  },
  _rows: function() {
    return this.obj.find(this.options.childrenSelector);
  },
  _totalPages: function() {
    return Math.ceil(this._totalRows() / this.options.limit);
  }
   };
 };

 $.fn.paginate = function(options) {
switch(options) {
  // Example of custom actions:
  // case 'destroy': return pagination.destroy(this);
  default: return Paginator().build(this, $.extend( {},     
   $.fn.paginate.defaults, options));
}
};

$.fn.paginate.defaults = {
limit: 20,
initialPage: 0,

previous: true,
previousText: '<',
next: true,
nextText: '>',
first: true,
firstText: '<<',
last: true,
lastText: '>>',

optional: true,

onCreate: null,
  onSelect: null,

  childrenSelector: 'tbody > tr',
  navigationWrapper: null,
  navigationClass: 'page-navigation',
   pageToText: function(i) { return (i + 1).toString(); }
  }

 }(jQuery));
```

Comment: Copy the 4 lines after `// Add 'last' button` to add a new button and set `limit`, eg `$("#table").paginate({limit: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER })`

Comment: I did find my solution...by adding "_rows().show().slice(index * this.options.limit, (index + 1) * this.options.limit).show();" and renaming the existing ">>" button.  But adding a new button would also work...Thanks